# Отправить несколько форм сразу

Tags: javascript

Нужно отправить несколько форм одним нажатием. Все должны открыться в новом окне. Вот код, отравляется только последняя форма.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function SendForm () 
{
 document.form0.submit();
 document.form1.submit();
}
</script>

<form name="form0" method="post" action="tech.php" target="_blank">
 <input type="hidden" value="">
</form>
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="tech2.php" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" value="">
 </form>

 <input type="button" onclick="SendForm();" value="Отправить">
```

Comment: а про ajax вы что-нибудь слышали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что происходит при нажатии кнопки submit?
Осуществляется переход на новую страницу, при этом передаются переменные из формы.
То есть просто так отправить два запроса на чистом html не получится. Чтобы одновременно отправилось две формы, должно открыться две разные страницы.

Я вижу два решения.

1. Отправлять одну из форм в новом окне. При этом параметры получится передать только методом get. Проще говоря собрать все данные одной из форм, сформировать строку запроса и присоединить ее к УРЛ. После чего получившийся УРЛ+строка запроса открыть в новом окне.
2. Делать два ajax запроса.
   Собрать данные каждой из форм и отправить обе аяксом.

Comment: В IE этот метод работает, буду пробовать